# Rails before_action a or b with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I have two before_actions, A and B.
For example, if the country that the user login from Asia, I want to run the before_action A. Otherwise, I'd like to run the before_action B.

I have a function to check where the login is made from, called `is_login_from_asia?`
I was originally thinking of the before action like this below,

`before_action :A, if: :is_login_from_asia?`

`before_action :B, if: :!is_login_from_asia?`

Is this the right way, or is there a better way (e.g., before_action + if/else) to implement this??
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
before_action :handle_login_from_asia

private

def handle_login_from_asia
  is_login_from_asia? ? A : B
end
```

Comment: Or, if necessary, `if: :is_login_from_asia?` and `unless: :is_login_from_asia?` but I'd agree that a single method is probably cleaner and avoids multiple calls to `is_login_from_asia?`